# Is given vector in spanned vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given vectors
$$
\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}  1 \\ -4 \\ 17 \end{pmatrix},
\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\  2 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix},
\vec{w}=\begin{pmatrix} -2 \\  3 \\  1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

My task is to check whether $\vec{u}$ is in the spanned vector space of $\vec{v}, \vec{w}$.

I got first my matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & -2 &  1 \\
  2 &  3 & -4 \\
 -3 &  1 & 17
\end{pmatrix}
$$
After solving the system of linear equations I got the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & -1 \\
  0 & 1 &  2 \\
  0 & 0 &  0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

What is the final conclusion or rather solution and how to solve and find whether is $\vec{u} \in \mathrm{span}\left(\vec{v}, \vec{w} \right)$ or not?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Since you got a row of zeros, there must exist such numbers $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ that $$a \vec{v} + b\vec{w} = c \vec{u}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your aim is to find if there exist scalars $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha v+\beta w=u$, and the matrix of this linear system is what you have written. Since the rank of such matrix is 2 (as you can see after the reduction), just like the rank of the coefficient matrix, a (unique) solution exists, i.e. $u$ lies in the span of $v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

You have proved that the system $\alpha v+\beta w=u$ (in the unknowns $\alpha$ and $\beta$) has a solution, so $u$ belongs to the span of $v$ and $w$.

If you want to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you can perform back elimination: sum to the first row the second row multiplied by $-2$ (some denote this as $R_1\gets R_1-2R_2$):
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -5 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which tells you that $u=-5v+2w$.